# WebAuthenticationBroker and Facebook: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings

Tags: c#, facebook, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I have an existing Universal App. Trying to implement Facebook login.

I added Windows App to the Facebook app and pasted there the App SID from Windows Store (the ms-app://s-1-15-2-... thing without ms-app://) according to http://facebooksdk.net/docs/windows/sso/.

This is the code to get the auth url

```
var client = new FacebookClient();
 var url = _facebookClient.GetLoginUrl(new
                {
                    client_id = Config.FacebookAppIdCZ ,
                    redirect_uri = WebAuthenticationBroker.GetCurrentApplicationCallbackUri().AbsoluteUri,
                    scope = "email,public_profile",
                    display = "popup",
                    response_type = "token"
                });
```

When I then call

```
WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateAndContinue(url);
```

on Windows Phone, the auth broker shows the Facebook login UI and everzthing works fine.

However on Windows when I call

```
var auth = await WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateAsync(WebAuthenticationOptions.None, url);
```

The Facebook tells me

```
Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains.
```

I guess this is a Facebook configuration problem, but I am stuck. I am sure the App SID is correct, it is the same in the Windows Store and when I call `WebAuthenticationBroker.GetCurrentApplicationCallbackUri()` (because the app is already associated with the store).

Comment: What is the actual value of `redirect_uri`?

Comment: ms-app://s-1-15-2-... same as in the store

Comment: having the same problem here..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a temporary glitch made by Facebook, see https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1448059258828537/?__mref=message_bubble. If things like this happen again, consider making an alternative login by using and approach as I describe here http://dotnetbyexample.blogspot.com/2015/06/custom-oauth-login-to-facebook-for.html

Answer (score 0):

maybe redirect_uri has different value from a platform to an other.

i had this error on asp when the complete redirect url was not in the field

**Valid OAuth redirect URIs** (fb app -> Settings -> Advanced -> OAuth Settings)

you can also try to add the domain of the redirect _url to App Domains.

An other thing, did you try with fiddler to see what's sended and received?

ps. excuse my bad english, i'm french.

Comment: There is no domain in apps. I tried adding the ms-app://s-1-15-2-...  to the valid OAuth redirect URIs but Facebook showed me an error that I cannot add this.

Comment: did you try without protocol?